# Using ASensorEventQueue_registerSensor or its alternative for API Level below 26

Tags: android-ndk, android-sensors, android-7.0-nougat

I am looking for a workaround for **ASensorEventQueue_registerSensor** or something equivalent for the android app with the MinSDK API level set to 24.